# MVVM Cross could not load plugin assembly for type MvvmCross.Plugins.Email.PluginLoader

Tags: c#, mvvmcross

I updated to MvvmCross Beta 3. Now it seems it can't find my plugins on Windows 10 UWP anymore.

This exception is thrown on start:

```
An exception of type 'Cirrious.CrossCore.Exceptions.MvxException' occurred in Cirrious.CrossCore.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: could not load plugin assembly for type MvvmCross.Plugins.Email.PluginLoader
```

I added the mail plugin via NuGet and added a bootstrapper to the project:

```
using Cirrious.CrossCore.Plugins;

namespace MoneyManager.Windows.Bootstrap
{
    public class EmailPluginBootstrap
        : MvxPluginBootstrapAction<MvvmCross.Plugins.Email.PluginLoader>
    {
    }
}
```

[image]

You can find the repository on GitHub: https://github.com/NPadrutt/MoneyManager

On Android the startup still works without any problem after adjusting the namespaces. Is there some known issue in the beta 3 or is there wrong in my setup?

Thanks
NPadrutt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug on MVVMCross 4(since it´s beta).

But it's a simple fix:

On your UWP Setup.cs, override method LoadPlugins and add this:

`Mvx.RegisterType<IMvxComposeEmailTask, MvxComposeEmailTask>();`

Comment or remove the Bootstrap for this plugin and it should work.

Edit: Bug has been fixed on the source code of MVVMCross(#1142), but still no new version has been made available on NuGet.

Answer (score 1):

Since assemblies have version numbers now you need to be on exact the same version of all libraries, which in your case will be MvvmCross 4.0-beta3.

You can also try to add this to your app.config:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Cirrious.CrossCore" publicKeyToken="e16445fd9b451819" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: The plugins are up to date.
Also I added a app.config to  the project with your code, but the exception still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem on Windows 10 UWP. The reason was that I was using "WindowsStore" as the suffix for the name of the UWP implementation of the Plugin. When I fixed this, by changing the suffix to "WindowsUWP", the Plugin loaded correctly.

Thanks to @CheeseBaron for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Seems I am having the same problem as others but with the PictureChooser plugin, not Email. Looking at the solution proposed for Email, two things came up. First, there is no override for 'LoadPlugins' in MvxWindowsSetup. Instead, I tried the following changes to setup.cs:

```
using MvvmCross.Plugins.PictureChooser;
using MvvmCross.Plugins.PictureChooser.WindowsStore;
using Cirrious.CrossCore.Plugins;

. . .

protected override IMvxPluginManager CreatePluginManager()
{
    Mvx.RegisterType<IMvxPictureChooserTask, MvxPictureChooserTask>();
    return base.CreatePluginManager();
}
```

Note, there was no 'WindowsCommon' namespace for PictureChooser, so I used 'WindowsStore' which was present as the result of the nugget package install. I then excluded the PictureChooserPluginLoader and I was able to proceed. Looks like there is a namespace issue in the 4.0.0.0-beta5 version of the PictureChooser plugin.

BTW: The email plugin loaded just fine and from the debug output was able to resolve the WindowsCommon namespace.

Comment: mh, it is strange that you don't have a LoadPlugins Method to override in the Windows Setup. Stupid question, but you're sure that you inherit from MvxWindowsSetup?